# I have designed a course activity, how can I turn this into a publication?

Tags: education, biology

I am a biologist I have only published in biology journals.

This time I would like to publish a more education centered paper if I can.

This is an undergraduate course activity that should take a few weeks.

I have looked online for education journals but haven't seen a "course activity" published per se.

Wondering if this sort of thing is publishable and if so in which journals.

Comment: If you're prepared to make the course activity material open source, then you could consider the Journal of Open Source Education https://jose.theoj.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That really depends.

- Is your course activity novel (from a pedagogical point of view, not just a new topic)? It doesn't have to be earth-shatteringly different, but do your research - just because a course has not been taught in a certain way at your university does not mean it's not common practice in other places.
- Are there lessons learned that others may be interested in hearing about?
- Do you have data (at least qualitative, ideally qualitative and quantitative) that suggests your new way of teaching brings tangible benefits?

If those are true, then you can certainly write an education-focused paper. But, like with any paper, you do actually need to do your research and provide a scholarly view on your proposal, you cannot just write down what you do and call it a day.

Comment: Which databases are suitable for my literature search?   Regards

Comment: Don't see why Google Scholar wouldn't be fine for a lit search (perhaps someone who works in education/pedagogy can correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 5):

One of the things that makes teaching Biology so challenging is that you have to be constantly redesigning your labs to keep up with the field. Some of the changes we make are part of what is often called the "pedagogical approach", i.e. where do you place the needle in the spectra of experimentation vs. demonstration, free-flow vs. structured protocols, hands-on vs. lecture/instruction-based, narrative-based vs. not, etc. ([for example](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1319030111)) All of these issues are actively published in educational journals, and if you have data showing that your new lab activity supports better learning outcomes, well, yes, you should try to publish those results.

However, what it seems you have is just a new lab activity for which you want to get the type of publication credit that goes into a CV. There are many alternatives, some of them peer-reviewed. For example, [look at this from Genetics Society of America](https://genetics-gsa.org/education/gsa-prep/). Other possibilities, albeit not peer-reviewed, include lab sharing sites such as [Lab Exchange](https://www.labxchange.org/library). There are also many organizations with repositories of lab activities, with varying levels of curation, for example https://most.oercommons.org/ . Most university libraries also manage repositories of Open Educational Resources (OER), which can "officially" publish your lab activity ("publish" as opposed to say, you just putting a PDF of it on your faculty profile page.)

If you think that your new lab activity is that good, I would get IRB approval, test some hypothesis related to learning outcomes and submit to a peer-reviewed journal. This is just based on my experience, but the peer-reviewed activities published by professional societies tend to become obsolete quickly and they are rarely updated. I prefer OER repositories both to place my own lab activities, and when I'm looking for ideas.